# How to add a custom column in customer table in Magento2?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

I want to add a custom column(Telephone) in **Customer** table in magento2 and want to add value in this field while customer registration.

For this first I create a column(Telephone) in DB in **customer_entity** table.While create customer when I call $customer->setTelephone('1234567890') in **Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php in execute function**. It is giving an error **Undefine function setTelephone in Magento/Customer/Model/Data/Customer.php**. But I already create this function in this Model.

**Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php**

```
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/create', ['_secure' => true]);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $this->session->regenerateId();

    try {
        $address = $this->extractAddress();
        $addresses = $address === null ? [] : [$address];

        $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
        $customer->setAddresses($addresses);

        //Here is I set the telephone and it is giving an error
        $customer->setTelephone('1234567890');
```

**Magento/Customer/Model/Data/Customer.php**

```
public function setTelephone($telephone)
{
    return $this->setData(self::TELEPHONE, $telephone);
}

public function getTelephone()
{
    return $this->_get(self::TELEPHONE);
}
```

**Magento/Customer/Api/Data/CustomerInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Customer\Api\Data;

interface CustomerInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface
{
    /* Add this code*/
    const TELEPHONE = 'telephone';

    public function getTelephone();

    public function setTelephone($telephone);

}
```

---

Tried to do with custom module.But its giving an error.

`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Onjection_Customer data: current version - none, required version - 1.0.0...`

**Module Code**

1. app/code/Onjection/Customer/registration.php

   ```
   <?php

       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
           \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
           'Onjection_Customer',
           __DIR__
       );
   ```

2.app/code/Onjection/Customer/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Onjection_Customer" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>           
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence> 
    </module>
</config>
```

3.app/code/Onjection/Customer/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Onjection\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mobile',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_address_edit'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Commands used for installation :

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: That's not the right way to work with Magento. See [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute). You should not modify core files either.

Comment: @subroutines How to add this custom attribute on customer registration page?Is their any method to do this without creating module?

Comment: `telephone` is already an existing customer address attribute, you can look into customizing `magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml` to show it on the registration page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom customer Attribute
Adding Customer Attribute

1) Create the Module file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Kalpesh_Mobile"  setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>           
            <!--<module name="Kalpesh_Mobile"/>-->
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>



class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        protected $customerSetupFactory;

        /**
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;

        /**
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
                    $setup->startSetup();


            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()-
      >getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mobile',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_address_edit'],
            ]);

            $attribute->save();

                    $setup->endSetup();



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own module

in Magento simple module  example You can check the https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sampleform_form.xml they have provided functional for adding a new field

```
<field name="color">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <!--component constructor-->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/js/form/element/color-select</item>
            <!--main template for form field that renders elementTmpl as a child template-->
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <!--customized form element template that will show colors-->
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_SampleForm/form/element/color-select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Autumn colors</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sampleform</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

in m2 there is no need to edit mysql rows directly or change core code, everything you could and suppose to rewrite. Read docs about general principles of working with magento 2

and as mentioned  in comments if you need telephone field it's already implement